# how can I test two strings against one variable using IF

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement

I want to test if the $ip is equal to one of the two values: "a" or "b". When I test against only "a" it works. I didn`t want to do || and perform another grep+cut, since I have done those once, I would like to take the result and test it against these 2 values.

```
if [[ $(grep -e "$ip" FILE |cut -d' ' -f5) =~ 'a\|b'; then
 echo "OK"
fi
```

Comment: Could you add the language in the question tags as this is obviously not language-agnostic?

Comment: added [tag:linux], [tag:bash] and [tag:unix]

Comment: remove the backslash and quotes on the match part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do another grep+cut, you can always assign the result to a variable.  Regex match is not equivalent to equality check.  The following will be more readable

```
var=...; if [[ "$var" = "a" || "$var" = "b" ]]; then echo OK; fi
```

Comment: You can also use `[[ $var = @(a|b) ]]`; versions of `bash` prior to 4.1 will require running `shopt -s extglob` first to allow the extended pattern syntax.

Comment: didn't know this thanks, actually better to convey intention.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` statement is a readable alternative

```
case "$(grep ...)" in
    a|b) 
        echo OK
        ;;
    *)
        echo not OK
        ;;
esac
```